# Automate gpgtar encryption bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, gnome-terminal, nautilus

hHello :)

I am trying to automate a script (that runs from within Nautilus scripts folder) that encrypts folders locally:

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=abcd1234ABCD
for i in {1..8} ; do
    echo -n "${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}"
done

gpgtar -e -c -o "$chars" $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

I want the name of the encrypted file to be random. This process looks to work great since I get prompted to insert a password, that is, until I check the file size of the encrypted file, attached as a screenshot.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ? Have been searching for a couple of days on this topic but cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are never changing the value of `${chars}`

Comment: Have you considered using `chars=$(mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX')` ?

Comment: @steve hi, yes you are correct, but at the moment that is not the issue, since i'm testing the script, and the file get deleted afterwards.